# Hello I just started with google cloud storage, size of bucket online help doesnt

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I need to be able to see how much space my bucket is using, but when I followed the online help to add 'total bytes' metric to my dashboard but I cannot find this metric.

I would like to be able to monitor how much storage I am using.

Thanks for any help